# why all affiliate markets don't use (rel="noreferrer noopener") in affiliate links?

Tags: html, security, hyperlink, seo, affiliate

I searched in most famous affiliate markets like slick deals and others, but I found that they just use `rel="nofollow"` and don't use `rel="noreferrer noopener"` in all there affiliate links to Amazon and others.

I understand that these rel tags use like that.

> `noreferrer`: use in security with (_blank) pages to don't refer any information about user or website to this blank page.
>
> `noopener`:use also in security but to prevent js codes.
>
> `nofollow`: use for SEO and doesn't any effect on secure.

so depend on that, are affiliate markets don't care about the security of these links because of all links for pig brands and no problems with these links?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question

Comment: but it related to security, and also the website has SEO tag so where is the problem

Comment: Security is also off-topic for non-programming question. Also, I recommend clicking on the SEO tag and reading it....

Comment: so , where I can add this question?

Answer (score 0):

**noreferrer**: Doesn't send referral information to the target website. Some affiliate programs require that you do not do this so that they know where their links are being clicked on from.

**noopener**: This is fine to use because it prevents granting a new browser context to the document that opened it.

**nofollow**: If you don't use this, then search engines can "click" your link and it will create false impressions/clicks.

**Recommended**:

```
rel="nofollow noopener"
```